# Visual C++ and C# interop

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, dllexport

I have the following minimal example:

Suppose we have three libraries:

- CoreLibrary (C# .NetFramework library)
- ExportLibrary (C# .NetFramework library, but with DllExports library)
- CppTests (C++ Native Unit Test Project).

The libraries contains one file each:

#### CoreLibrary.cs

```cs
// sample Class1 class.
namespace CoreLibrary{
    public class Class1{}
}
```

#### ExportLibrary.cs

```cs
using CoreLibrary;

namespace ExportLibrary
{
    public static class DllExports
    {
        [DllExport]
        public static int Fun1()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        [DllExport]
        public static int Fun2()
        {
            return 6;
        }

        [DllExport]
        public static int Fun3()
        {
            var class1 = new Class1();
            return 7;
        }
    }
}
```

#### CppTests.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace CppTests
{
    typedef int (*func_type)();

    TEST_CLASS(CppTests)
    {
    public:


        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            HMODULE mod = LoadLibrary(L"ExportLibrary.dll");
            func_type MyFunct = reinterpret_cast<func_type>(GetProcAddress(mod, "Fun1"));
            int result = MyFunct();
            Assert::AreEqual(5, result);
        }
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod2)
        {
            HMODULE mod = LoadLibrary(L"ExportLibrary.dll");
            func_type MyFunct = reinterpret_cast<func_type>(GetProcAddress(mod, "Fun2"));
            int result = MyFunct();
            Assert::AreEqual(6, result);
        }
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod3)
        {
            HMODULE mod = LoadLibrary(L"ExportLibrary.dll");
        
            func_type MyFunct = reinterpret_cast<func_type>(GetProcAddress(mod, "Fun3"));
            int result = MyFunct();
            Assert::AreEqual(7, result);
        }
    };
}
```

The idea is to be able to test interoperability between C++ and C# (new libraries written in C#, run on the old legacy C++ app) from the actual interoperability.

Problem is, when CppTests is referencing CoreLibrary and ExportLibrary, I have passed TestMethod1 and TestMethod2, but not TestMethod3 - apparently using class from outside library is the big problem.

The only thing I changed in config of libraries were CoreLibrary and ExportLibrary Platform target to x86. C++ project doesn't use CLR. Also, I've tested the case on the old Borland C++ Studio 6.0, and there code is run without problems.

Comment: Well, test failed.  C# likes throwing exceptions at basic mishaps, the [DllExport] hack leaves you without any guess why the code did not work.  A very serious usability concern.  You can get ahead with the debugger, use Project > Properties > Debugging > "Debugger type" = Mixed and Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, CLR Exceptions ticked.  A typical reason is that the assembly that contains Class1 could not be found.  Get truly ahead by doing interop with C++/CLI or [ComVisible(true)]